# Is add reference to a Class Library(Package) project in old Web project possible

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

i have a running WebApi 2 project and i would like to investigate the upgrade path to Asp.NET 5. My upgrade path would be:

- Upgrade libraries one by one using the appropriate target framework
- Upgrade tests
- Upgrade WebApi project to new Asp.NET 5.

With my first library converted i was unable to add the reference to any project not using the new template!
Is this the tooling? Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot (at this time) reference a DNX project from a csproj.  You could however create nuget packages of the project using `dnu pack` and reference those in your csproj.

You can however reference a csproj from a DNX project via VS2015 or by using `dnu wrap`.

Comment: @davidfowl that's good to hear. it is the only way to migrate incrementally  from a existing project to the new one by changing one by one! Do we have a date?