# Add DNX class library reference to an ASP.NET 4 web application

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, .net-core, dnx

Is it possible to add a reference to a DNX/Core CLR class library project to a ASP.NET 4 web application without having to use a NuGet package?

I'm using VS2015 and have a single solution containing some newer DNX class libraries and some legacy ASP.NET projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is not currently possibly to that, however [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34062260/is-add-reference-to-a-class-librarypackage-project-in-old-web-project-possible/34068159#comment55917712_34068159) suggests it will be possible some time soon (RC2).